# Retrievieng time offset of local computer with respect to an NTP Server

Tags: c++, windows, api, ntp, datetimeoffset

I am currently developing a c++ code on Windows OS which uses windows api to set and get system time as I need to apply some offset to my local time (in the range of few seconds). As in my final configuration I will be connected with my computer with an NTP server, I was wondering if there's some windows api to get the offset I have with respect to the NTP server I am connected with.

Currently I found this on stackoverflow which uses w32tm,

https://serverfault.com/questions/891684/how-to-get-the-ntp-offset-and-delay-values-in-windows-systems

but is there some function I can call directly from c++ to compute this offset?
Or do I need to do a system call and read the output in some ways?

Thanks

Comment: How about [std::chrono::utc_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock) from [<chrono>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

Comment: but will it measure the time on the basis of my system time (which will be with an offset with respect to the NTP server I am connected with) or on the basis of the NTP server time?

Comment: According to Einstein's General Theory Of Relativity, the described task cannot be done without violating some fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe. I have my doubts that Microsoft Windows managed to find some loophole to them.

Comment: NTP's offsets and transmission delays are approximate and based on the presumption that the transmission delays are the same in both directions, which they of course are not.  So, do not code with the false presumption that offsets will be global/exact/equal.  See https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/time.html.